# Создание объекта в foursquare

Tags: json, php

Подскажите как это делать. 
Если пройти по адресу вида: 
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/add?ll=$lat,$lon&name=$name&address=$adres&city=almaty&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret
Выходит такая ошибка:
{"meta":{"code":405,"errorType":"other","errorDetail":"This endpoint only supports POST."},"response":{}}

Как я поняла, надо использовать Post-метод. Но как им тут пользоваться?

Comment: Мысли пытаюсь черпать от сюда:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/add

Еще встретила вот такую вот функцию для прикрепления фотки к месту:
<form action="https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add" 
method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p>Venue ID: <input type="text" name="venueId"></p>
<p><input  type="file" name="photo"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="oauth_token" value="YOUR TOKEN HERE">
<input type="submit">
</form>

Comment: это json вообще-то

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделала сама по примеру с картинкой.

```
<form action="https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <p>Наименование: <input type="text" name="name" value="Шоколад"></p> <p>Долгота,широта: <input type="text" name="ll" value="43.235009,76.910449"></p> <p>Адрес: <input type="text" name="address" value="ул. Жандосова 8А"></p> <p>Город: <input type="text" name="city" value="almaty"></p> <input type="hidden" name="oauth_token" value="мой TOKEN"> <input type="submit"> </form>
```

теперь осталась только малость, немного видоизменю.

Comment: возникла новая ошибка: где name латиницей, выходит ошибка данных... т.е. место не создается